# Gnome Terminal Massively Slows Down When Slightly Off Screen

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, wayland, antergos, lag

I'm running [gnome terminal](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/) with a standard [Antergos](https://antergos.com/) install using [GNOME](https://www.gnome.org/) with [Wayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/). When the terminal is just slightly off screen it lags like like crazy when I'm trying to scroll. I'm running [zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) with a couple plugins to provide autocomplete and highlighting. This happens especially in [vim](https://www.vim.org/) and less when trying to scroll or quit.

How would I go about debugging this?

Comment: @K7AAY Their migration plan is to basically to switch the repositories to be straight arch. So it will pretty much end up being arch. I'll eventually get around to migrating back to arch, but it's setup correctly right now, and I don't feel like breaking it.

Comment: How do you _exactly_ scroll? By pressing some key (e.g. Shift+PageUp in zsh, PageUp or Up in vim, etc.)? Or by grabbing the scrollbar and dragging with the mouse? Or two-finger scrolling with touchpad? Etc...

Comment: What does "massively slows down" and "lags like crazy" mean? Does it take 0.1 seconds to respond, or 1 second, 10 seconds, 1 minute...? Does it happen all the time (after every keypress or scrolling mouse event), or sometimes only (about how often)?

Comment: @egmont it seems to stop responding and actually being able to scroll or update

Comment: I can't reproduce it with mainstream GNOME; also I have the feeling that if it was a generic problem, it probably would have been already reported by many folks. My first wild guess is that Antegros might have a faulty patch somewhere.

Comment: If you really wish to debug the problem yourself, I'd start by checking whether other apps (including other VTE-based and non-VTE-based terminals) suffer from the same problem. Also try how it behaves on X11 instead of Wayland; or another desktop / window manager.